# SonicWall NSA2400 after firmware upgrade to 5.9 - not able to log some intrusion prevention/detection statements

Tags: firewall, sonicwall, intrusion-detection, intrusion-prevention

After upgrading firmware to 5.9 version I'm not able to log intrusion prevention/detection for statements like PHP CGI Argument Injection, Remote Command Execution, Remote File Inclusion, WEB-ATTACKS, etc.

I have enabled alerts for IPS and IDP with a priority - Alert.

Any clue what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Because: *Sonicwall...*

Comment: The 5.9 and later firmware seems to break a lot of things.  I just had a support issue [detailed here](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/sonicwall-nsa-2600-routing-issues-with-multiple-lan-interfaces-configured) regarding ARP table issues.  During troubleshooting we were told not to update our 2400 to 5.9 as it caused the same issue.  I'd recommend opening a support case as the issue we had went all the way to engineering...

Comment: I have done that too. Just was curious if it is something common or not, so maybe here ppl heard/saw solution for that.